# Search category in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, label

I'm using Outlook categories to class email and contact.

Is there a way to search through category the same way than in GMail?

Something like "category=Work AND category=Germany".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me in Outlook 2010.

In the search Inbox (at the top of your message list Ctrl+E), type..

```
category:Work category:Germany
```

Comment: Work great! Just think to translate "category" into your language (I'm french so I had to write "catégorie:Work").

Comment: Unfortunately for me it seems to do an "OR" search instead of an "AND" search...

Answer (score 1):

Came across this answer while searching on a related question for myself. In addition to the info provided by the other two answers, there are TONS of great search tips for Outlook at this link. (including how to perform OR searches, or narrow down on several criteria, including relative time searches, like "from:Bossman AND received:last month")

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-Outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da

Answer (score 0):

Although it 'works' to search for "category" without the colon, that does not actually find all docs marked with ANY category, for me. However this does the trick: "followupflag:followup flag". One may add a subsetting word to search for after that phrase, as well.